# Button inside is listView is not displayed in view in UWP

Tags: c#, listview, uwp, uwp-xaml, xamarin.uwp

I tried creating a listView with a button inside it in xamarin UWP but i am getting a blank output window. I tried something like this

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Button Text="CLick"/>
                    </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
     </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Help me to create a list view in xamarin UWP. If any errors, correct me. Thanks in advance

Comment: You have no item source bound to your listview. Thats why it is blank

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Basic example

This example will show a single Button inside a ListView.
This way you directly add the Button as children.

```
<ListView>
      <Button Text="CLick"/>
</ListView>
```

This should also work with multiple children.

```
   <ListView>
          <Button Text="CLick"/>
          <Button Text="CLick2"/>
    </ListView>
```

## Advanced example

This example will show a collection of buttons in your listview. The number of buttons depends on how many items there are in your collection. You need to make use of the [ItemsSource](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.ItemsView%3CTVisual%3E.ItemsSource/) Property.

In your code behind / viewmodel you'll need some IENumerable/ICollection type named ListViewItems that holds atleast one element.

### Sample ContentPage XAML

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App1.Views.ListViewExample">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ListViewItems}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Button Text="CLick"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Further Explanation

---

For each item in your [bound](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_binding_basics/) collection a Grid with a Button as child will be created.